# Swift @objc protocol with optional function implemention causes build error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, swift-protocols

I have the following protocol (which I'm using as a IBOutlet reference to the storyboard, so it must be with @objc).

```
/// This protocol implemented by views that contain a **main** 
    collection view.
@objc protocol CollectionInViewMethods {

      /// Notify the view that scrolling occurred.
      @objc optional func setSortingMenuFrame(newFrame: CGRect)
}
```

When I try to access the optional function using the swift syntax as follows:

```
self.cineamsView.setSortingMenuFrame?(newFrame: CGRect())
```

Which results with

```
Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11
```

While force unwrap build successfully (! instead of ?)

Is there any reason for that to happen? I saw that objective C does support optional functions in protocols, it seems to me like an Xcode bug...

Comment: is it swift 3 code?

Comment: @Dari yes, the project is written in Swift 3.

Comment: It seems xcode has some issues on handling CGRect on optional function.

Comment: @Dari Haha, I guess you are right, I changed the input argument to Integer and it compiled!

Comment: This is a known bug – [see SR-2268](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2268)

Comment: Ok, so I guess this issue is solved. 
I know it's not related to this issue, but anyone else experienced the bug with Xcode, which fails when trying to navigate to protocol function declaration? (using command B on a property that conform to it).
It also fail to show the documentation from the protocol on the functions. 
It's so frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to unwrap the function first see if it's not nil before calling it (only if you bridge it with a objective-c protocol)

This blog explains it:
http://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-optional-protocol-methods/